Authoring attribute driven text label SLDs for QGIS
I'm attempting to create attribution-driven SLDs, for text labels, that will work within QGIS.  This is giving me issues and I'm not quite sure how to proceed.  As a simplistic example of what's happening, the following sample SLD is drawing upon four attributes - 'textstring', 'geo_x', 'geo_y' and 'rotation'.  The 'textstring' attribute is certainly being queried correctly, as the expected text then appears on the map as you'd expect.  If, as a quick test, I replace 'textstring' with 'rotation' within that  tag, then the rotation values appear on the map instead (also as you'd expect).  However, when it comes to including 'rotation'/'geo_x'/'geo_y' within the tags that they're supposed to relate to, they don't work and the Anchor and Rotation just get set to their default values.  Replacing these attributes with hard-coded values, though, causes the SLD to behave as expected.  I've been wondering, then, whether there's an issue with the attributes defaulting to strings, in case it's that which is messing things up.  However, I've not yet spotted a way to prove this, nor do I have any other ideas.
Can you see what might be going wrong?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Custom Carto Text</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Custom Carto Text</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label><ogc:PropertyName>textstring</ogc:PropertyName></Label>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
                <AnchorPoint>
                  <AnchorPointX><ogc:PropertyName>geo_x</ogc:PropertyName></AnchorPointX>
                  <AnchorPointY><ogc:PropertyName>geo_y</ogc:PropertyName></AnchorPointY>
                </AnchorPoint>
                <Rotation><ogc:PropertyName>rotation</ogc:PropertyName></Rotation>
              </PointPlacement>
          </LabelPlacement>
        <Fill><CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter></Fill>
        </TextSymbolizer>
       </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>



what does the log file say? after you turn logging upto to GeoTools-Dev? what values are in the attributes? You could try wrapping them in a parseDouble or parseInt function to see if it is the string issue

Hi Ian...thanks for your suggestions.
As far as parseDouble/parseInt go, do you know the specific format for those that you'd expect to work in this context?  I just tried a few variations of additional tags, but none made any difference.  So, maybe I'm not thinking about it in the right way?
Guy

Also, the 'General' log returns the following error message, which I don't really understand, as the attribute values, when used within the  tags at least, are being returned correctly.
2024-06-27T16:52:00     WARNING    Error executing query: SELECT id,styleName,description FROM layer_styles WHERE f_table_catalog='osdata' AND f_table_schema='osmm_topo' AND f_table_name='cartographictext' AND f_geometry_column='geom' AND (type='Point' OR type IS NULL) ORDER BY useasdefault DESC, update_time DESC
